# Replace recursively from a replacement map

Tags: python, regex

I have a dictionary in the form

```
{'from.x': 'from.changed.x',...}
```

possibly quite big, and I have to substitute in text files accordingly to that dictionary in a quite big directory structure.

I didn't find anything which might any nice solution and I end up:

- using os.walk
- iterating through the dictionary
- writing everything out

WIth something like:

```
def fix_imports(top_dir, not_ui_keys):
"""Walk through the directory and substitute the wrong imports
"""
    repl = {}
    for n in not_ui_keys:
        # interleave a model in between
        dotted = extract_dotted(n)
        if dotted:
            repl[dotted] = add_model(dotted)

    for root, dirs, files in walk(top_dir):
        py_files = [path.join(root, x) for x in files if x.endswith('.py')]

        for py in py_files:
            res = replace_text(open(py).read(), repl)


def replace_text(orig_text, replace_map):
    res = orig_text
    # now try to grep all the keys, using a translate maybe
    # with a dictionary of the replacements
    for to_replace in replace_map:
        res.replace(to_replace, replace_map[to_replace])

    # now print the differences
    for un in unified_diff(res.splitlines(), orig_text.splitlines()):
        print(un)

    return res
```

Is there any better/nicer/faster way to do it?

EDIT:
Clarifying a bit the problem, the substitution are generated from a function, and they are all in the form:

```
{'x.y.z': 'x.y.added.z', 'x.b.a': 'x.b.added.a'}
```

And yes, sure I should better use regexps, I just thought I didn't need them this time.
I don't think it can help much, however, because I can't really formalize the whole range of substitutions with only one (or multiple) regexps..

Comment: That's not a dictionary.  Can you explain the problem more?

Comment: I'm sure Matt said it's not a dictionary because if you look at `{'from.x', 'from.changed.x',...}`, it's obviously not a dictionary, missing as it is either keys or values.

Comment: Sorry you are right I fixed it, I thought it was something related to the functions.

Comment: Are there any patterns in the replacements that you might be able to use to simplify the problem?

Comment: What is **not_ui_keys** ? What does **extract_dotted(n)** ? What is **add_model**  and where does it come from ? Is **replace_map** the dictionary ``{'from.x': 'from.changed.x',...}``  ?

Comment: How many elements are there in **replace_map** ? Is **replace_map** constant ? - Do you know the use of regexes ?

Comment: **replace()** doesn't perform in-place replacement, you must reassign the result to the same identifier: ``res = res.replace(to_replace, replace_map[to_replace])`` . - Repeating `res.replace()'' , hence doing as many replacements as there are elements in ** replace_map** isn't good practice. You must find another algorithm. That's possible with a regex

Comment: If the files are on Unix, learn how to use 'rename' - http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/renaming-multiple-files-at-a-shell-prompt.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would write the first function using generators:

```
def fix_imports(top_dir, not_ui_keys):
    """Walk through the directory and substitute the wrong imports """
    from itertools import imap,ifilter
    gen = ifilter(None,imap(extract_dotted, not_ui_keys))
    repl = dict((dotted,add_model(dotted)) for dotted in gen)

    py_files = (path.join(root, x)
                for root, dirs, files in walk(top_dir)
                for x in files if x[-3:]=='.py')
    for py in py_files:
        with open(py) as opf:
            res = replace_text(opf.read(), repl)
```

`x[-3:]=='.py'` is faster than `x.endswith('.py')`

Comment: Hm, I wonder why the slicing comparison is faster than the method call .

Comment: @jathanism: no method lookup, no method call

Comment: @jathanism I also was wondering. I had only performed tests that had shown me this result. Thanks to the answer of John Machin, I now  wonder no more.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you everyone, and about the problem of substituting from a mapping in many files, I think I have a working solution:

```
 def replace_map_to_text(repl_map, text_lines):
     """Take a dictionary with the replacements needed and a list of
     files and return a list with the substituted lines
     """
     res = []
     concat_st = "(%s)" % "|".join(repl_map.keys())
     # '.' in non raw regexp means one of any characters, so must be
     # quoted ore we need a way to make the string a raw string
     concat_st = concat_st.replace('.', '\.')
     combined_regexp = re.compile(concat_st)

     for line in text_lines:
         found = combined_regexp.search(line)
         if found:
             expr = found.group(1)
             new_line = re.sub(expr, repl_map[expr], line)
             logger.info("from line %s to line %s" % (line, new_line))
             res.append(new_line)
         else:
             res.append(line)

     return res

 def test_replace_string():
     lines = ["from psi.io.api import x",
              "from psi.z import f"]

     expected = ["from psi.io.model.api import x",
                 "from psi.model.z import f"]


     mapping = {'psi.io.api': 'psi.io.model.api',
                'psi.z': 'psi.model.z'}

     assert replace_map_to_text(mapping, lines) == expected
```

In short I compose a big regexp in the form
(first|second|third)

Then I search for it in every line and substitute with re.sub if something was found.

Still a bit rough but the simple test after works fine.

EDIT: fixed a nasty bug in the concatenation, because if it's not a raw string '.' means only one character, not a '.'